# Jinja keep indentation on include or macro

Tags: templates, jinja2

I am wondering if there is any way to keep the indentation with jinja when adding a include or macro inside a file. I would like to use jinja to generating a code file. An example would be

File: class.html

```
class MyClass:
     def someOp():
         pass

     {% include "someOp.html" %}
```

File: someOp.html

```
def someOp2():
    pass
```

The result of the template should be:

```
class MyClass:
     def someOp():
         pass

     def someOp2():
         pass
```

If there any way to make jinja prepend the indent before the include tag for each line in the included file? Or is there any way to customize jinja to do this?

Comment: This is something I would also like to see.

Comment: I'd also find this useful, especially when trying to make either yml files (where indentation is important, but more difficult to understand across multiple files) or anything that needs to be human-readable

Answer (score 39, accepted):

One way is to wrap the include in a macro, then because the macro is a function, its output can be passed through the indent filter:

```
class MyClass:
    def someOp():
        pass

    {% macro someop() %}{% include "someOp.html" %}{% endmacro %}
    {{ someop()|indent }}
```

By default 'indent' indents 4 spaces and does not indent the first line, you can use e.g. 'indent(8)' to indent further, see http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters for more details.

If what you're including is defined as a macro to begin with then the further wrapper macro is not needed, and you can jump straight to using the indent filter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems almost like what I need, but can I make it use the indent level of the line it is on (instead of explicitly stating the level)?

Comment: Can I provide this macro on Python side during rendering, so that I don't have to re-implement it in every template?

Comment: I used this method as a base for rendering a yaml file and noticed that it left empty lines behind where the macro was defined use `{%- macro someop() -%}{% include "someOp.html" %}{% endmacro %}` to avoid this.

Comment: Hi @Razvi this answer auto-indents as you ask: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58027589/2480947

Comment: Using filters https://stackoverflow.com/a/53775887/795876

Answer (score 9):

I was looking in Jinja2 to achieve the same and got to conclusion aligning multi-line block indentation with the originating Jinja statement is not possible currently.

I've posted a small PR to Jinja to add a new syntax `{%* ... %}` and `{{* ... }}` that does exactly this. See the PR for details:

https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/919

Comment: PR is merged, but nothing was changed in docs (at least in https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.indent ). Unfortunately, it doesn't work in Jinja templating in Ansible (may be Ansible uses older version of Jinja?). In this case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991479/jinja2-correctly-indent-included-block

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier if Jinja provided the facility. It looks like [some work was done on this](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/919) but the issue is currently closed (20 Nov 2019) and the pull request hasn't yet been merged. It could be because things get tricky quite quickly with indents (think of tabs and spaces, for example.)

The following is a simple solution I've found effective for generating Python code which, of course, needs to handle indenting well. It copes with files that use spaces for indentation.

`auto_indent()` detects the indent level of a variable in a host template, then applies that indent to a piece of text.

```py
import os
import itertools
import jinja2


def indent_lines(text_lines: list, indent: int):
    return [' ' * indent + line for line in text_lines]


def matching_line(s, substring):
    lineno = s[:s.index(substring)].count('\n')
    return s.splitlines()[lineno]


def is_space(c):
    return c == ' '


def indentation(line: str) -> int:
    initial_spaces = ''.join(itertools.takewhile(is_space, line))
    return len(initial_spaces)


def auto_indent(template: str, placeholder: str, content_to_indent: str):
    placeholder_line = matching_line(template, '{{ ' + placeholder + ' }}')
    indent_width = indentation(placeholder_line)
    lines = content_to_indent.splitlines()
    first_line = [lines[0]]  # first line uses placeholder indent-- no added indent
    rest = indent_lines(lines[1:], indent_width)
    return os.linesep.join(first_line + rest)
```

Example:

```py
action_class = """\
class Actions:

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def prequel(self):
        pass
    
    {{ methods }}
    
    def sequel(self):
        pass
"""

inserted_methods = """\
def create_branch():
    pass

def merge_branch():
    pass
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    indented_methods = auto_indent(action_class, 'methods', inserted_methods)
    print(jinja2.Template(action_class).render(methods=indented_methods))
```

Example output:

```
>>> python indent.py
class Actions:

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def prequel(self):
        pass
    
    def create_branch():
        pass
    
    def merge_branch():
        pass
    
    def sequel(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 3):

I've written a [`jinja2` extension](https://github.com/stereobutter/jinja2_workarounds) to work around this long standing issue. It automates the previously proposed solution of using  `{% filter indent(...) %}` by hooking into the `preproccess` api provided by `jinja.ext.Extension`.

If you add the extension in your `jinja.Environment` you can use the following syntax to include templates that get indented correctly into the rest of your template. Notice the `indent content` directive.

```
class MyClass:
 def someOp():
     pass

 {% include "someOp.html" indent content %}
```

The result of rendering then becomes

```
class MyClass:
 def someOp():
     pass

 def someOp2():
     pass
```