# Jinja2 correctly indent included block

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have two files:

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>{{title}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       {% block content %}
       {% endblock %}   
    </body>
</html>
```

**register.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="" method="post" name="register">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.login.label }} {{ form.login(size=20) }}
    {{ form.password.label }} {{ form.password(size=20) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

It gets rendered like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Register</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="" method="post" name="register">
    <div style="display:none;"><input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="1393257771.168161##ce877b3519f192c05d3b409f3b7b07bb147dead7"></div>
    <label for="login">login</label> <input id="login" name="login" size="20" type="text" value="">
    <label for="password">password</label> <input id="password" name="password" size="20" type="password" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>

    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to achieve this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Register</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <form action="" method="post" name="register">
            <div style="display:none;"><input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="1393257771.168161##ce877b3519f192c05d3b409f3b7b07bb147dead7"></div>
            <label for="login">login</label> <input id="login" name="login" size="20" type="text" value="">
            <label for="password">password</label> <input id="password" name="password" size="20" type="password" value="">
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something? I tried Google and messing with the template indentations, also `indent` filter does not seem to apply here. I do not want to hard-code the indentation in the inner block, as that would break if I decide to change the formatting and elements in the base later.

Comment: If you indent register.html with 8 spaces, you get the desired result.

Comment: @voscausa - This is exactly what I want to avoid. The indentation in `base.html` may change. I do not want to re-indent `register.html` every time.

Comment: related question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821539/jinja-keep-indentation-on-include-or-macro/71467956#71467956

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jinja keep indentation on include or macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821539/jinja-keep-indentation-on-include-or-macro)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Although I think the increase in document size is a good argument against "correctly" indenting documents, [jinja2 actually provides a function](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#indent) to do just what you what:

```
indent(s, width=4, indentfirst=False)
```

which you would use in your `base.html` with a macro, as described in [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10997352/677122).

I would probably make that a macro anyway and call it `render_register_form`:

```
{% macro render_register_form(form) %}
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" name="register">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ form.login.label }} {{ form.login(size=20) }}
        {{ form.password.label }} {{ form.password(size=20) }}
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
{% endmacro %}
```

and then include it where needed, for example, with 8 spaces indentation, as:

```
{{ render_register_form(my_form)|indent(8, True) }}
```

Comment: What about `{% call render_register_form(my_form) %}`?

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment is addressing @GillBates... Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Using indent on Jinja 2.10 escapes my HTML. Is this normal?

Comment: @Usagi I have the same problem, did you find a solution on how to use the indent filter without escaping the html syntax, or how to unescape it again afterwards

Comment: You can try the recommendations from http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping thus either the `| safe` filter or using `MarkupSafe.Markup` before passing content to the template.

Answer (score 84):

I know, the question is rather old but I found a nice solution to this problem.
You can apply filters to whole text blocks: [Template Designer Documentation / Filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#id11)

```
{% filter indent(width=4) %}
{% include "./sub-template.yml.j2" %}
{% endfilter %}
```

Answer (score 4):

Good question. I believe Jinja2 does not do this.

The main question you need to ask yourself is why you want the HTML to be correctly indented, since browsers do not care. In a production application it is more efficient to go the other way and strip all the white space to make the page smaller.

If you are interested in doing this during development then you can pass the HTML generated by `render_template()` through an indenter such as `prettify()` from BeautifulSoup. I do not recommend this for a production system, since your functions will take longer to run.

Comment: I still face this problem because i am trying to preporocess RAML with jinja2 :)

Comment: I know that OP is, but something to consider is that not everyone is using Jinja within HTML files.  For example, in [Cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter), Jinja can be interspersed in non-code files, such as Markdown where an extra tab indent due to whitespace is significant.

Comment: Browsers might not care, but _I_ do.

Comment: I'm rendering yaml. Indentation is important.